# pseudo-element shifts after resizing browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I defined pseudo-element after for my menu. And it looks like this:
[image]

Whenever I click on other link, it moves under that link:
[image]

I defined this pseudo element like this:

```
    top: 100%;
    left: 25.8%; //Changed according to the link
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-top-color: #344553;
    border-width: 16px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    @include transition(left 0.7s ease);
```

To move my pseudo-element, I simply change my "left" attribute.

The problem is if I resize browser, My pseudo-element shifts to the left:
[image]

Is there any way to make it fixed? Or calculate its position using JS? Or maybe there is some js library for calculating such stuff?

Thank you!

Comment: I would use a different approach: add the pseudo-element to the menu item, instead of the entire menu, using an `.active` class. Then you can center it beneath the menu item regardless of the screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `screen.width;` to find the current width of the screen. You can use that to write a JS function to move your pseudo-element depending on the width of the screen.

Or you can give your nav bar elements a fixed width for certain screen sizes and add responsive breakpoints in your CSS to change the width of the nav bar.